# How to determine the convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{n^2}}{(n+x)^{n^2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I've been studying for my analysis exams, and I've come across a series I haven't been able to solve. The question is just to determine for which real values of $x$ does the series **converge**. I've figured out it does converge for positive values and diverges for negative values of $x$.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{n^2}}{(n+x)^{n^2}}$$

However, the only value that I've actually been able to prove properly is $x=0$, and just because in that case it's trivially easy as the limit of the general term is $1$ (and hence it's not $0$).

Not sure how to prove the other cases. I'm guessing the way is probably factorizing the denominator, but I haven't gotten farther than that.

Comment: You're welcome (to M.SE ;-)...

Comment: You might use something like $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1+x/n)^{n^2}/e^{xn}=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the Root Test. Note that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+x}{n}\right)^n=e^x.$$

Comment: Oh thanks André, I'm going to get down to work. I'll feed back :)

Comment: Alright, I just finished and it worked perfectly! Hence I accept your answer. The method was pretty straightforward, I guess I need some more study hehe. Thanks again for your help :D

Comment: You are welcome. The Root Test gives no information at $x=0$, but that is easy to handle separately.

Answer (score 5):

**Root Test**:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} |\frac{n^{n^2}}{(n+x)^{n^2}}|^{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^n}{(n+x)^n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \frac{n}{n+x} \right)^n =...$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I wish I could accept several answers, I'm accepting André's one because it is the same idea but he replied earlier, but else your answer would as well be totally accepted ;)

Comment: No problem, glad to help.